# How to do component validation in Angular JS or in HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, validation

I am learning angular JS from past 4 days and now I want to do component validation like valid email,only character only integer.These kind of validations supported by jquery.My question is that Is angular js also provided this kind of validation or I have to use any API for that or any validation API supported by HTML5.

Regards

Comment: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation Angular JS Form Validation

Answer (score 0):

Angular supports validation by exposing a validation model on the scope that you can bind to, or check for validity.

## Angular Validation

Say you have a form and you give it a name:

```
<form name="myForm">
```

Angular uses this name to bind a model on the scope called myForm.

In this case, it is

```
$scope.myForm
```

The validation model also has the following validation properties that you can bind to, or validate against.

```
$scope.myForm.$valid    // form is valid?
$scope.myForm.$invalid  // form is invalid?
$scope.myForm.$pristine // is the form untouched?
$scope.myForm.$dirty    // is the form dirty? (opposite of $pristine)
$scope.myForm.$error    // this is a special error object that has validation flags
                        // that you can bind to as well.  More on this later...
```

For example, you can use these special properties in your controller:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
   if($scope.myForm.$valid) {
      // submit form...
   }
});
```

Or  bind them to error messages in your HTML:

```
<div ng-show="myForm.$invalid">Something is wrong!!</div>
```

There is also validation support for fields within a form. Like the form validation model, the input validation model also has the same properties.

Put an input text field inside a form element and give it a name:

```
<form name="myForm">
   <input name="myField" type="text" ng-model="name" />
</form>
```

The name is important. The name is used to define a property on your form model.  In this case, it is

```
$scope.myForm.myField
```

Like the form validation object, the field validation object also has the same validation properties:

```
$scope.myForm.myField.$valid    // form is valid?
$scope.myForm.myField.$invalid  // form is invalid?
$scope.myForm.myField.$pristine // is the form untouched?
$scope.myForm.myField.$dirty    // is the form dirty? (opposite of $pristine)
$scope.myForm.myField.$error    // this is a special error object that has validation flags
                                // that you can bind to as well.  More on this later...
```

$valid, $invalid, $pristine, and $dirty are Boolean flags.

The $error object, however, is special. It is a container for validation flags that are automatically set by angular directives or by custom directives that you create.

For example, you can add a *required* validation directive to a field with an ng-model:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myField" required />
```

The *required* validation directive will set the $error's *required* validity flag when the field is blank.

For example,

```
$scope.myForm.myField.$error.required
```

This allows you to bind to an appropriate error message in your HTML:

```
<div ng-show="myForm.myField.$error.required"> This field cannot be blank!</div>
```

That's Angular Validation in a nutshell,

Hope this was helpful